# How do I understand いいかしら

Tags: meaning, word-usage

My guess is that it's asking whether something is good or not, similar to saying **いいですか**.

So my question is what form is this and what does it stem from?

Comment: SE allowing identical usernames can sure be confusing at times. Anyway, questions about かしら have been asked several times before, and I recommend using the search function. See for example this: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/164/5176

Comment: @Will Certainly is. For a second, I thought your comment was bot generated because it had found a duplicate question. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As (the other) Will suggested in the comments, there are already several posts where you can learn more about the usage of かしら. As a short answer to your question:

Rather than いいですか, in most (if not all) situations it's better to think of it as a version of saying いいかも(しれない), e.g. after someone suggested something, it could be used as a response meaning like "a yeah, that might be good/work".

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, except いいかしら is feminine. If a dude was to utter it, it is, well, fabulous.

Just to confirm, as you wrote "something is good or not" - both いいですか？ and いいかしら？ are asking for permission/confirmation to go ahead, as opposed to asking if something is good or bad in quality.

similar:

- いいかな？casual
- いいかしら？feminine
- よろしいですか？formal

(seen in confirmation dialog of a software like, Deleting the file. Are you sure? ファイルを削除します。よろしいですか？)

Also look here, in the manga panel, a lady in Kimono is saying おとなり　いいかしら？ - may I sit next to you?

https://one-news.jp/article/rss/37609